# How to exclude some countries from a post on Facebook by geotargetting? (All countries except…)

Tags: facebook, geolocation, location, country, geotargetting

I would like to know how to exclude some locations from a post Facebook without selecting each country (where I want to put my post) on the Facebook list one by one.

Indeed, I would like to post some stuff with a visibility on All locations EXCEPT few countries (like Australia, US and few others).

I want to do this without selecting each country (208 countries) from the facebook list… 
Is there a way to select a visibility on All locations except 2 or 3 countries for a post Facebook (by programming code or something)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the FB Post button for visitors from certain countries through back-end codes. You just need to perform IP-COUNTRY lookup based on each visitor's IP address and decide to show or hide the button.

This is not a fool-proof solution because anyone can still go to your FB page and post a comment. But it should be able to reduce the postings.